# how to avoid camera landscape mode in android?

Tags: android

HI

I am New To android, my problem is when iam capturing image programetically the camera is opening in landscape mode..Than How to Avoid it?

Can anyone help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I think you should use

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

in your camera class.

Answer (score 1):

You can set above line in your androidmanifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".activityname" android:orientation="portrait"/>
```

This will open your camera activity in portrait mode only.